# Clearly display small font size

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, font-size

What techniques (or different fonts) could I use to fonts to make small text (about 10px) look nice in Photoshop?

Here is what I tried, but every time it looks blurry, or too bold:

[image: example]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Pixel Fonts.](http://www.google.com/webhp?hl=en&q=&tab=iw#hl=en&safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&q=pixel%20Fonts&oq=pixel%20Fonts&gs_l=hp.3..0l4.537.2169.0.2356.11.11.0.0.0.0.209.1339.0j9j1.10.0...0.0.IhVQAYcs18g&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=e4316f9ee5086259&biw=1285&bih=1351) These are fonts designed to not use or rely on anti-aliasing and be clear and legible at very small sizes. Most of the fonts have a range of 1 or 2 sizes they can be used at specifically.

A great place for pixel fonts is [fontsforflash.com](http://www.fontsforflash.com/)

When using a pixel font, you want to turn off all anti-aliasing within Photoshop for the text.