# Text get all messed up in small dimensions in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am trying to learn the correct way to import bmp to a Nintendo Nes tile editors , all the settings seems identical with tile editors  :

width : 72 px
height : 8 px
Resolution : 8 px
Color Mode : RGB 8 bit
Background Contents : Black
Color Profile : Don't Color Manage This document
Pixel Aspect Ratio : Square Pixels

I work at zoom 1000% and gives this :

[image]

When I zoom out to original size 100% it gives this :
[image]

And this is the best result I had , I almost get more creepy text.

And I have to save it to exact resolution , cause all tile editors import images and don't resize them.

IS there any solution ? thank you

Comment: You aren't going to get much better than that at 8px tall.. What you need is a font designed to work at that size... See [A font that's readable with a 5px height](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/91478/52050)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clearly display small font size](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/8321/clearly-display-small-font-size)

Answer (score 1):

There's an anti aliasing text rendering option in Character panel that I think in your case it have been set on "None" option, change it to "Crisp" or "Smooth" when your text layer's selected.

[image]